# Open Source Desktop Tool to Style MapBox Vector Tile Data for MapBox

Tags: vector, style, mapbox, desktop-gis

I have MapBox Vector Tile data in the form of mbtile files that needs to be styled for MapBox.  Need a desktop application to work with data locally that will allow the style to be saved locally as style.json.  I have looked at QGIS, but it does not appear to let you save as styles compatible with MapBox.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this task?

Comment: See https://pkgeo-org.github.io/vector%20tiles/2018/04/30/Maputnik.html.

Comment: A library to export QGIS projects and layer symbology from QGIS into the Mapbox GL style..... https://github.com/planetfederal/lib-mapboxgl-qgis